# Abstract Algebra and Real Analysis. Onto and 1-1 functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

May you tell me if my solution is correct? Thank you so much!

Here is the problem:

[image: Abstract Algebra problem]

Part a)

$f(x,y)=\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y).$

Part b)

There are infinite different real numbers that are equal to $xy$.

Example $xy=2x(y/2)=3x(y/3)$

$f(x,y)=f(2x, y/2)= f(3x,y/3).$

However,

$(x,y)$ not equal to $(2x, y/2)$ not equal to $(3x, y/3).$

Then any ordered pair in the codomain $H\times H$ is connected to infinite number of ordered pairs in the domain $G\times G$.

In other words, $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ does not imply $(a,b)=(c,d)$.

Then $f(x,y)$ is not $1$-$1$.

Comment: Part a.) doesn't work, as the logarithm is not defined for negative numbers. However, $f(x)= \ln(\vert x \vert)$ will work.

Comment: Actually F is a mapping with one variable.

Comment: Hint for part b.): Have a look at $f(x^2)=f((-x)^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part you may use $f(x)=\ln\lvert x\rvert$, to make it defined on the all nonzero real numbers.

EDIT: For the second part, as Severin Schraven has pointed out, you may write:

$f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)+f(1)$ from where you get $f(1)=0$

$0=f(1)=f((-1)\cdot(-1))=f(-1)+f(-1)=2f(-1)$, so $f(-1)=0$

So $-1\ne 1$, but $f(1)=f(-1)=0$, so $f$ cannot be injective/bijective

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! What about part b?

Comment: Amazing explanation!

Answer (score 2):

For part (b):

Suppose $F:\Bbb R^{\ast} \to \Bbb R$ is such that $F(xy) = F(x) + F(y)$.

Clearly, $F(1) = F(1\cdot 1) = F(1) + F(1) \implies F(1) = 0$.

Also, $0 = F(1) = F(-1\cdot -1) = F(-1) + F(-1) = 2F(-1) \implies F(-1) = 0$; so $F$ is not injective.